# When does a protocol function get called?

Tags: ios, swift

I have adopted a protocol in viewController class and defined it's method (only one method). The method is suppose to update an array which is initially empty. Here is some code.

```
var contact = ContactList()


func getContactData( entry: ContactListEntry ) {

    contact.updateEntry(entry)

}
```

also

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    self.detailViewController?.delgate = self
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as      UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = contact.entries [indexPath.row].firstName

    return cell
    }
```

It's giving fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer
(lldb)

My question is, at what point does getContactData () get called? I need it to be called before the tableView functions so I can make the array available with something in it.

Comment: Which function? Your protocol is called when you use it...

Comment: @Wain My question is, at what point does getContactData () get called? I need it to be called before the tableView functions so I can make the array available with something in it

Comment: `getContactData` will be called when you call it. Typically you would do this in `viewDidLoad` or maybe in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. let me try that

Comment: You can answer your self that question very easily by putting some println() here and there. You'll then see which one is called first. You also should check if your optional is not null before trying to access its values: if contact != nil etc ...

Answer (score -1):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called when iOS needs to display the cell. This is also true for other methods from `UITableViewDataSource`